# Addressing Formatting and Figure Alignment Issues in Project on Overleaf

Tags: sidewaysfigure, gap

I'm have two issues with my project on Overleaf. First, there is a gap between sections or paragraphs, as seen in the image. Here's how it is written in LaTeX:

```
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
Figure \ref{fig:sem} shows  a picture of SEM analysis of the a silica surface coated with gold nanorods. The obtained results further supports the results obtained from the UV-Vis. The SEM image confirms the presence of both nanorods, this is correlated with the peak at 900 nm, and other shapes that are correlated with the peak around 500 nm.

\input{figure/sem}

\section{Interaction analysis, glass surfaces}

It's important to highlight that, In this section, the utilized AMP is CC-AMP, which is thiol-terminated.
```

[image]

The second issue is that I need to ensure the figures are at the same height:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
     \centering
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.65\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure/Bare silica surface with NaOH.png}
         \caption{QCMD measurements conducted on bare silica surface with NaOH . The measurment starts with the addition of NaOH to assess the extent of silica etching. Then, NaOH is added after the peptide to increase the pH of the system and the change the charge of the peptide. This was done to induce repulsion between the peptide and the silica surface, thereby reducing the attachment of the peptide to the surface. }
         \label{fig:QCMD bare silica surface with NaOH}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hspace{6 pt}
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure/Coverage bare silica surface with NaOH.png}
         \caption{The mass of the peptide immobilized on the silica surface.}
         \label{fig:Coverage bare silica surface with NaOH}
     \end{subfigure}
     \caption{Bare silica surface with NaOH.}
        \label{fig:bare silica surface with NaOH}

\end{figure}
```

[image]